# What's another word for considered ?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-patterns

I was always considered different ? 
I have always been labeled as different ? 
I have always been categorized as different ?

Is there a good word I can replace "considered" with ?

Comment: Do you have a good reason for not wanting to use it? I would have thought it the best word to use. Labeled is Ok, I would not use categorized if speaking of family/friends who thought you different.

Comment: If this is indeed part of a resume or some such self portrait, saying that you have always been different to everyone else isn't flattering. Instead you'd say something like you always strived to achieve above others. Just being different isn't an asset.

Comment: How about 'thesaurused'?

Answer (score 1):

*Regarded as*?  *Thought of as*?  *Called*?

Answer (score 1):

Seen as, perceived as. *Considered* does seem like the best option.